How to fetch line items information from razorpay orders made via storefront pages?
I was trying to fetch product information from orders object received after a payment has been done via storefront page in Razopay. I was able to receive a list inside order object named line_items, it contains unique ids of the products added in storefront page during payment, but I am not able to fetch the information of these products with their id and also was not able to find any API to accomplish this from the razorpay docs. It would be helpful if somebody could mention an API or a way to fetch the products information from payment_pages.
The order object looks like below:
{
  id: 'order_id',
  entity: 'order',
  amount: 500,
  amount_paid: 500,
  amount_due: 0,
  currency: 'INR',
  receipt: null,
  offer_id: null,
  status: 'paid',
  attempts: 1,
  notes: { line_items: '[{"qty":1,"amt":500,"liId":"li_id"}]' },
  created_at: 1728282584,
  cod_fee: 0,
  shipping_fee: 0,
  line_items_total: 500
}

How to fetch information of liId in line_items??
Edit: I figured out that we couldn't do it for the time being, had to look for other e-commerce alternatives to integrate payments with.
